# How do I change Ace-editor's behavior in case of CSS?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

In the cms, I use templates that can be edited using Ace-editor. The editor opens in CSS-mode and from a dropdown I can change to 'smarty'. Is there a way to modify it's behavior that in case Ace-Editor 'thinks' it's a CSS-template it will open in smarty mode?

Been poking in this part of the code, but no luck.

```
if (currentMode == 'css') {
    $('head').append('<script src="'+moduleDir+'/lib/Ace/src-min/mode-'+cssPrefMode+'.js></script>');
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/'+cssPrefMode);
    var selectedMode = cssPrefMode;
  } else if (currentMode == 'php') {
    $('head').append('<script src="'+moduleDir+'/lib/Ace/src-min/mode-'+currentMode+'.js></script>');
    editor.getSession().setMode({path: 'ace/mode/'+currentMode, inline: true});
    var selectedMode = currentMode;
  } else {
    $('head').append('<script src="'+moduleDir+'/lib/Ace/src-min/mode-'+currentMode+'.js></script>');
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/'+currentMode);
    var selectedMode = currentMode;
  }

I expect Ace-editor in case of CSS to open in smarty-mode.

Edit: made a change in the file ext-modelist --> CSS:"smarty|tpl", but that didn't make any difference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ace itself doesn't detect the mode, the code doing that is in the cms.

Comment: Ok, thnks. In that case, is there a way to 'fool' Ace, meaning in case it 'thinks' CSS it opens with the Smarty editor?

Comment: it's hard to tell without knowing more about the issue, what is the code snippet that you show in your question?